# c# I have to do phonebook

Tags: c#

Actually in the phonebook from its features to add members I did it but it has to be sorted as I don`t know how to do it can anyone help me please , Thanks and here is the code

Records are stored as struct (Subscriber) and stored in List (subscribers)

```
namespace phonebook
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<Subscriber> subscribers = new List<Subscriber>();
        public void Add()
        {
            Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the firstname");
            subscriber.firstname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the lastname");
            subscriber.lastname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the streetname");
            subscriber.streertname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the city");
            subscriber.city = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the country");
            subscriber.country = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the buildingnumber");
            subscriber.buildingnumber = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the phonenumber");
            subscriber.phonenumber = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the email");
            subscriber.email = Console.ReadLine();
            subscribers.Add(subscriber);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    public struct Subscriber
    {
        public string firstname;
        public string lastname;
        public string streertname;
        public string city;
        public string country;
        public string buildingnumber;
        public string phonenumber;
        public string email;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to Sort it depending on the fristname you can try this:

```
subscribers.Sort ((sub1,sub2)=>sub1.firstname.CompareTo(sub2.firstname));
```